# In TFS 2010 is it possible to copy queries from one project to a project in a different collection?

Tags: collections, tfs, copy

To reproduce:
Right click on a folder of queries in Team Explorer and select **COPY**.
Right click on *servername* and select **Connect to Team Project**.
Connect to project in different collection
In query section of the 2nd project right click on query folder.

**Paste** option is dimmed out.

However if I reconnect to the original project in the 1st collection paste is not dimmed.

Is there any way to copy Queries between collections, preferably in blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can done in a graphical way.
But if you have the [WIQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130198.aspx)-equivalent of the query, it's transportable/executable - possibly with minor adaptations.
So if you have a custom tool that executes the query, it could be used between different TFS Collections.

Comment: I was able to copy queries btwn collections as follows.  

Connected to old collection and project.  
Open query for edit  
Save as in file (.wiq format)
Opened .wiq file in text editor
Replaced occurrences of old collection name with new collection name.  
Replaced occurrences of old project name with new project name  
In my case the old project had fields that did not exist in the new project, so deleted references to non-existent fields using text editor.  
Opened new collection and project.  
Opened edited .wiq file  
Saved query in server.  

Repeat for each query to be copied.

Comment: @JonN I didn't get the "Saved query in server" part. how do you do that?

Answer (score 5):

VS 2013, I right clicked on My Queries (selected all of them), copied them, then went to another instance of VS opened to a different project, right clicked on My Queries and pasted them into that project.

Then modified anything specific to the original project.